# Why does Microsoft advise against readonly fields with mutable values?

Tags: c#, immutability

In the [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057.aspx), Microsoft say:

> **Do not assign instances of mutable types to read-only fields.**
>
> The objects created using a mutable type can be modified after they are created. For example, arrays and most collections are mutable types while Int32, Uri, and String are immutable types. For fields that hold a mutable reference type, the read-only modifier prevents the field value from being overwritten but does not protect the mutable type from modification.

This simply restates the behaviour of readonly without explaining why it's bad to use readonly. The implication appears to be that many people do not understand what "readonly" does and will wrongly expect readonly fields to be deeply immutable. In effect it advises using "readonly" as code documentation indicating deep immutability - despite the fact that the compiler has no way to enforce this - and disallows its use for its normal function: to ensure that the value of the field doesn't change after the object has been constructed.

I feel uneasy with this recommendation to use "readonly" to indicate something other than its normal meaning understood by the compiler. I feel that it encourages people to misunderstand the meaning of "readonly", and furthermore to expect it to mean something that the author of the code might not intend. I feel that it precludes using it in places it could be useful - e.g. to show that some relationship between two mutable objects remains unchanged for the lifetime of one of those objects. The notion of assuming that readers do not understand the meaning of "readonly" also appears to be in contradiction to other advice from Microsoft, such as FxCop's ["Do not initialize unnecessarily"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182274(VS.80).aspx) rule, which assumes readers of your code to be experts in the language and should know that (for example) bool fields are automatically initialised to false, and stops you from providing the redundancy that shows "yes, this has been consciously set to false; I didn't just forget to initialize it".

So, first and foremost, *why do Microsoft advise against use of readonly for references to mutable types?* I'd also be interested to know:

- Do you follow this Design Guideline in all your code?
- What do you expect when you see "readonly" in a piece of code you didn't write?

Comment: 100% agree. Typical Microsoft guideline. \*flush\*

Comment: I cannot say that I am free of bias. ;)

I felt that Anthony's answer, while accurate, didn't say anything that wasn't already stated in the guideline: readonly references to mutable objects are bad... because the object is mutable. On the other hand, your answer did at least elaborate on why you might want to have readonly references to mutable objects. Now that I look at it, perhaps stakx's answer is - strictly speaking - the most accurate answer to the question I originally asked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I **agree with you completely**, and I **do** sometimes use `readonly` in my code for mutable reference types.

As an example: I might have some `private` or `protected` member -- say, a `List<T>` -- which I use within a class's methods in all its mutable glory (calling `Add`, `Remove`, etc.). I may simply want to put a safeguard in place to ensure that, no matter what, **I am always dealing with the same object**. This protects both me and other developers from doing something stupid: namely, assigning the member to a new object.

To me, this is often a preferable alternative to using a property with a private `set` method. Why? Because `readonly` means **the value cannot be changed after instantiation, even by the base class**.

In other words, if I had this:

```
protected List<T> InternalList { get; private set; }
```

Then I could still set `InternalList = new List<T>();` at any arbitrary point in code in my base class. (This would require a very foolish error on my part, yes; but it would still be possible.)

On the other hand, this:

```
protected readonly List<T> _internalList;
```

Makes it **unmistakably clear** that `_internalList` *can only ever* refer to one particular object (the one to which `_internalList` is set in the constructor).

So I am on your side. The idea that one should refrain from using `readonly` on a mutable reference type is frustrating to me personally, as it basically presupposes a misunderstanding of the `readonly` keyword.

Comment: +1, perfectly agree, private + readonly = less worries in code.

Comment: I do use private readonly on reference types a lot. It is perfect to ensure i never touch my dependencies in a class. I never expect a readonly private field to be immutable. That said i don't understand the ms guidline either. I think it is better to keep using the feature instead of protecting unaware developers of lessons they should definitely learn.

Comment: This example is the very reason that the guidance exists! You interpretation of why `readonly` is helpful is the very situation that most noobs misinterpret as being `immutable`. The guidance is suggesting you use a different construct that makes the intent clearer

Answer (score 28):

It seems natural that if a field is readonly, you would expect to not be able to change the value or *anything having to do with it*. If I knew that Bar was a readonly field of Foo, I could obviously not say

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = new Baz();
```

But I can get away with saying

```
foo.Bar.Name = "Blah";
```

If the object backing Bar is, in fact, mutable. Microsoft is simply recommending against that subtle, counterintuitive behavior by suggesting that readonly fields be backed by immutable objects.

Comment: You say that seems natural, but it does not seem so to me. It might seem *desirable* that there be some means of specifying deep immutability, but it does not seem *natural* that readonly should be it, and even that does not obviously lead to the conclusion that we should behave *as if* that were readonly's actual meaning when it is not.

Comment: It is concerning that the accepted answer only reinforces the need for the MS guidance.  I think your explanation is clearer than the MS wording: _readonly fields be backed by immutable objects (only)_

Answer (score 8):

> ***DO NOT** assign instances of mutable types to `readonly` fields.*

I had a quick look in the *Framework Design Guidelines* book (pages 161-162), and it basically states what you've already noticed yourself. There's an additional comment by Joe Duffy that explains the guideline's raison-d'être:

> *What this guideline is trying to protect you from is believing you've exposed a deeply immutable object graph when in fact it is shallow, and then writing code that assumes the whole graph is immutable.* 
>  — Joe Duffy

**I personally think that the keyword `readonly` was named badly.** The fact that it only specifies the const-ness of the reference, and not of the const-ness of the referenced object, easily creates misleading situations.

I think it would have been preferable if `readonly` made referenced objects immutable, too, and not just the reference, because that is what the keyword implies.

To remedy this unfortunate situation, the guideline was made up. While I think that its advice is sound from the *human* point of view (it's not always obvious which types are mutable and which aren't without looking up their definition, and the word suggests deep immutability), I sometimes wish that, when it comes to declaring const-ness, C# would offer a freedom similar to that offered by C++, where you can define `const` either on the pointer, or on the pointed-to-object, or on both or nothing.

Comment: While I sort of understand your point, one thing I definitely *don't* wish for is the horrible C++-style `const`.

Comment: _@JS Bangs:_ Of course this comes down to personal preferences. C's type declaration syntax is indeed... well, "special", but offers a lot of flexibility. C's `const` would probably not fit well into the relative simplicity of C#/.NET's type system... yet I sometimes miss it. `const` is a more powerful tool than many people think.

Comment: Upvoted, but I do disagree on the one point that readonly should make referenced objects immutable. I can't see that working without a system even more complex than C++'s const: when you access an object through a readonly reference, does that make all its properties and fields return readonly references? What about its method return values? Do you need a way to explicitly declare methods const/readonly? How does it all work when the object is of a type declared in another assembly?

Comment: What you're saying then (and if this summary is correct I agree with you) is that the guideline exists solely to mask the fact that the readonly keyword is not terribly well named. If you understand what readonly really does there should be no problem in using it in the stated scenario. My 2c.

Comment: @Weeble: What would be useful would be a means of specifying that more than one type of reference could exist to a class object, and that different properties should be accessible based upon the type of the reference.  I would expect that one could in theory allow up to four types of references reasonably efficiently if the address stored in each object reference was 1/4 the actual start address of the object, freeing up the upper two bits to identify the reference type.  I really doubt Microsoft will ever do such a thing, though.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are looking for is supported by the C++/CLI language:

```
const Example^ const obj;
```

The first const makes the referenced object immutable, the 2nd makes the reference immutable.  The latter is equivalent to the readonly keyword in C#.  Attempts to evade it produce a compile error:

```
Test^ t = gcnew Test();
t->obj = gcnew Example();   // Error C3892
t->obj->field = 42;         // Error C3892
Example^ another = t->obj;  // Error C2440
another->field = 42;
```

It is however smoke and mirrors.  The immutability is verified by the compiler, not by the CLR.  Another managed language could modify both.  Which is the root of the problem, the CLR just doesn't have support for it.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a few such peculiar advices. The other one that immediately springs to mind is not to nest generic types in public members, like `List<List<int>>`. I try to avoid these constructs where easily possible, but ignore the newbie-friendly advice when I feel the use is justified.

As for readonly fields - I try to avoid public fields as such, instead going for properties. I think there was a piece of advice about that too, but more importantly there are cases now and then when a field doesn't work while a property does (mostly it has to do with databinding and/or visual designers). By making all public fields properties I avoid any potential problems.

Comment: You raise a good point - do the design guidelines apply only to non-private members? The guidelines already say not to use public or protected fields. I suppose they are focused on the public API of a library, on which private fields obviously have no bearing. I certainly don't feel a pressing need to have *public* readonly mutable fields, since I rarely feel a need to have public fields at all.

Answer (score 1):

In the end they are just guidelines.  I know for a fact that the people at Microsoft often don't follow all of the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

This is legal in C# (simple Console App)

```
readonly static object[] x = new object[2] { true, false };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        x[0] = false;
        x[1] = true;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x[0], x[1]); //prints "false true"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

that would work. but that wouldn't make sense. bear in mind the variable x is readonly, and has not changed (i.e. the ref of x has not changed indeed). but that's not what we meant when we said "readonly x", is it? so don't use readonly fields with mutable values. It's confusing and counter-intuitive.