# Use case to understand why a list of strings should be declared as readonly

Tags: c#, clr

I am trying to understand what use cases would require me to declare a List<string> as a ReadOnly type.

An associated question with this is: How much memory upon instantiation of a list gets allocated?

Comment: Do you mean something like `private readonly List<string> myList = new List<string>();`?

Comment: Haven't pondered much on Private accesor, but we can go with private too.

Comment: Easy use case would be null reference exception prevention.  Or to ensure that multiple objects assigned the same list can not be accidently reassigned.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The main reason to mark a field as `readonly` is so that you know that regular code cannot have swapped the list reference. One key scenario where that might matter is if you have other code in the type that is performing synchronization against the list using a `lock(theListField)`. Obviously if someone *swaps* the list instance: things will break. Note that in most types that *have* a list/collection, it isn't expected to *change* the instance, so this `readonly` asserts that expectation. A common pattern is:

```
private List<Foo> _items = new List<Foo>();
public List<Foo> Items => _items;
```

or:

```
public List<Foo> Items {get;} = new List<Foo>();
```

In the first example, it should be perfectly fine to mark that field as `readonly`:

```
private readonly List<Foo> _items = new List<Foo>();
```

Marking a field as `readonly` has no impact on allocations etc. It also doesn't make the *list* read-only: just the field. You can still `Add()` / `Remove()` / `Clear()` etc. The only thing you can't do is *change the list instance to be a completely different list instance*; you can, of course, still completely change the contents. And read-only is a lie anyway: reflection and unsafe code can modify the value of a `readonly` field.

There *is* one scenario where `readonly` can have a negative impact, and that relates to large `struct` fields and calling methods on them. If the field is `readonly`, the compiler *copies the struct onto the stack* before calling the method - rather than executing the method in-place in the field; `ldfld` + `stloc` + `ldloca` (if the field is `readonly`) vs `ldflda` (if it isn't marked `readonly`); this is because the compiler can't trust the method not to mutate the value. It can't even check whether all the *fields on the struct* are `readonly`, because *that isn't enough*: a `struct` method can **rewrite `this`**:

```
struct EvilStruct
{
    readonly int _id;
    public EvilStruct(int id) { _id = id; }
    public void EvilMethod() { this = new EvilStruct(_id + 1); }
}
```

Because the compiler is trying to enforce the `readonly` nature of a field, if you have:

```
readonly EvilStruct _foo;
//...
_foo.EvilMethod();
```

it wants to ensure that the `EvilMethod()` can't overwrite `_foo` with a new value. Hence the gymnastics and the copy on the stack. Usually this has negligible impact, but if the struct is *atypically large*, then this can cause a performance problem. The same issue of guaranteeing that the value doesn't change also applies to the new `in` argument modifier in C# 7.2:

```
void(in EvilStruct value) {...}
```

where the caller wants to guarantee that it doesn't change the value (this is actually a `ref EvilStruct`, so changes would be propagated).

This issue is resolved in C# 7.2 by the addition of the `readonly struct` syntax - this tells the compiler that it is safe to invoke the method in-situ without having to make the extra stack copy:

```
readonly struct EvilStruct
{
    readonly int _id;
    public EvilStruct(int id) { _id = id; }
    // the following method no longer compiles:
    // CS1604   Cannot assign to 'this' because it is read-only
    public void EvilMethod() { this = new EvilStruct(_id + 1); }
}
```

This entire scenario doesn't apply to `List<T>`, because that is a *reference type*, not a *value type*.

Comment: I think you should bold this part: "And read-only is a lie anyway: reflection and unsafe code can modify the value of a readonly field." Other then that, great explanation. +1.

Comment: Why isn't `readonly struct` inferred automatically? The compiler knows whether any methods change `this` and a struct can't be extended to add new methods which change `this`. Are there reasons not to mark a struct `readonly` when it's possible?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov there's a fun scenario involving two projects referencing each-other and build order and changes that makes inference brittle - at least if you explicitly remove `readonly` you're making a **conscious decision** to break a contract - as opposed to accidentally breaking a contract that you *didn't know had been made* (by adding a method that mutates `this`). It would perhaps make a good code analyzer, though - *suggesting* when you can make a `struct` into a `readonly struct`

Comment: @MarcGravell This is a good reason to have `readonly struct` in the language, but doesn't seem to be a reason not to compile a `struct` as a `readonly struct` when it _can_ be detected. There is a similar case with tail recursion in Scala: a method marked `@tailrec` will fail to compile if it has non-tail recursive calls, but tail recursion is always compiled to a loop whether it's marked or not.

Comment: @MarcGravell I guess there is a scenario where `EvilMethod` method is added to the struct and an old method now calls it without recompiling the call site.

Comment: @MarcGravell Though I wonder what happens in similar situation if the call site was compiled with a `readonly struct` and at runtime it sees a new non-`readonly` version: verification error?

Answer (score 0):

> Using readonly you can set the value of the field either in the
>   declaration, or in the constructor of the object that the field is a
>   member of.

According to `List` this means that only reference to `List` object will be immutable (not inner strings). U can use `readonly` for `List` just in order to be sure that field reference will not be overriden.

here is an example [Why does Microsoft advise against readonly fields with mutable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804805/why-does-microsoft-advise-against-readonly-fields-with-mutable-values)

Answer (score 0):

Of all the classes you can work with in .NET, Strings have **by far** the oddest behavior. String is designed to operate like a value type, rather than a reference type, in many cases. And that is before we add string specific stuff like string-interning to the mix:

*[Comparing Values for Equality in .NET: Identity and Equivalence](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18714/Comparing-Values-for-Equality-in-NET-Identity-and)*

That all said, I do not know why anyone would mark a list<string> readonly, any more than a list[int] or a list[object].

How much memory is allocated: That is unpredictable. The list will grow as you add items to it. And it will overallocate, to avoid excessive re-allocation. But the exact algorithm for that is a framework implementation detail/class version detail. If you know how many items you need ahead of time, either give the count in the constructor or just build the list from your static source collection (like an Array). This can be a minimal performance increase and is generally good practice. At the same time, string interning will try to limit how much memory is allocated to the actual string instances in memory, by reusing references.

Comment: "String is designed to operate like a Value Type, rather then a reference type, in many cases" - I disagree with that statement. It behaves like an *immutable* type (at least most of the time); whether it behaves like a *value type* is a separate issue, and it absolutely always behaves like a reference type. Sure, most (not all) value-types are immutable, and most mutable types are reference-types, but these are orthogonal concerns.

Comment: Your argumentation only works if you consider all Structs to be value types. Children, rather then brothers.Or is there one Framework internal value type that is not inmutable? That does not use Value equality semantics?

Comment: structs *are* value-types; that is literally what they are. Lots of value-types are **not** immutable - examples: custom enumerators like [`List<T>.Enumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s(v=vs.110).aspx), or all the new `ValueTuple<...>` family: mutable structs. Equality is totally up to the type to define; many don't, and the `ValueType` base implementation uses field-by-field compare, but: a struct can do anything it wants. I don't understand your "Children, rather then brothers" remark, so I can't comment on that.